# How to resolve "sql(sqlContext...)' is deprecated" warning in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I'm building a new version of some old code using SparkR. Upon a block like this

```
hiveContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc)
hive_db = 'our_database'
db <- sql(hiveContext, paste0("use ", hive_db))
```

I'm told that `'sparkRHive.init' is deprecated. Use 'sparkR.session' instead.` So, okay, fine, I now have:

```
hiveContext <- sparkR.session(sc) 
hive_db = 'our_database'
db <- sql(hiveContext, paste0("use ", hive_db))
```

This runs, but now Spark warns `'sql(sqlContext...)' is deprecated. Use 'sql(sqlQuery)' instead.` I'm at a loss for what kind of input it's expecting here and would like to resolve this. Has anyone figured out what to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Spark 2.0 `sql` and the number of other functions (like `createDataFrame`) dont require `SQLContext` instance. Just:

```
sql(paste0("use ", hive_db))
```

Internally this will use [`getSparkSession`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/db44f5f3e8b5bc28c33b154319539d51c05a089c/R/pkg/R/SQLContext.R#L73-L79) to retrieve a session object.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the explanation. Strange objects, those SparkContexts...